# Javascript Draw2d - CanvasRenderingContext2D.implement is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas, mootools, compatibility, draw2d

In the browser console, when the page using draw2d library is loaded it appears "CanvasRenderingContext2D.implement is not a function". Is an important problem? The application seems to run correctly. I use mootools compatible with jquery, because in my application there is already jquery imported, so the problem could be this. Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the missing canvas element in IE version<8

The app itself is running well but you are unable to create "SVGFigures"
You can use excanvas for IE support.

Greetings

Comment: I use Firefox, so it is not a problem. Thanks very much